# When I color the eyebrows then go back to my body mesh the eyebrows arent colored

Tags: texturing, vertex-colors

I made a male with eyes eyebrows and eyelashes in makehuman then I exported him to blender. So in my side panel when I click on the eyebrows, eyes, eyelashes, and color them with vertex paint, then when I click back to my original mesh they are not colored. I don't know if I have to merge the eyebrows etc with the body or something?

Answer (score 1):

For seeing your paint in the viewport, you have to use texture shading (`Alt+Z`).

[image]

For rendering with blender internal, you have to assign a material to your eyebrows and to check "Vertex color Paint" in the material options :

[image]

For cycles, you have to use an Atttibute node (attribute name is 'Col' by default).

**Notes :**

- Vertex paint visualisation in viewport is only available for blender internal renderer.
- Depending what you want but it is often better to use "Texture paint" instead of "Vertex paint" for painting a model.